# Turtle issue with vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, attributeerror, python-turtle, python-3.10

Hi this is my first time trying to code video games in python.
So I found a tutorial video that was ran on the same opperating system as mine (mac) but when I wrote the setup in the video:

```
#Setup
import turtle

wn=turtle.Screen
wn.title("Pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, heigth=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()
```

This error appeared:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Does anybody knows what it means and how to fix it?
By the way I am running python 3.10.0

Comment: `turtle.Screen` is a function. `turtle.Screen()` **calls** the function and gives you back a window object that has the methods you're trying to call on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## t1

try this

```py
#Setup
import turtle

wn=turtle.Screen()#call the Screen like: Screen()
wn.title("Pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#Main game loop
while True:
    turtle.update()
```

does it worked??

Comment: Yes it did thanks man!!!

Comment: Answers to questions should provide an explanation of the problem and/or solution, not just contain code.

Comment: It worked but the window only appears for like a fraction of a second. Any advices?

Comment: did you use while true if not use.

Comment: I did used while true at the end of my program but it still doesn't work

Comment: It finally worked after I rewrote the whole program not sura what happened there but thanks guys!!!

Comment: @LéoLepage can you post the answer that worked, so it can help others who are facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

of t1 didn't worked try this

```py
#Setup
import turtle

wn=turtle.Screen()#call the Screen like: Screen()
wn.title("Pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#Main game loop
turtle.done()
```

try to use done instead of update
is it ok??